# How to obtain an equivalent to Pandas's "describe" method for tables in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to be able to get the main information regarding the various columns of tables located in **Snowflake**, like a `df.describe()` could do in Pandas:

- column names,
- data types,
- min/max/average for numeric types,
- and ideally unique values for string types
- maybe other things that I'm missing

Granted, you could simply pull all the data into a local DataFrame then do the "describe" in Pandas, but this would be too costly for Snowflake tables counting millions of rows.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to retrieve table-like results, so that I can also run some validation steps on these results: presence of columns, data types, distribution of the output...

Answer (score 1):

> *column names*
>
> *data types*

You could always query INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME ILIKE 'table_name';
```

Or

```
DESCRIBE TABLE 'TABLE_NAME';
```

---

> *min/max/average for numeric types*,
>
> *and ideally unique values for string types*
>
> *maybe other things that I'm missing*

**[Automatic Contextual Statistics](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-worksheets.html#automatic-contextual-statistics)**

> Select columns, cells, rows, or ranges in the results table to view relevant information about the selected data in the inspector pane (to the right of the results table). Contextual statistics are automatically generated for all column types. The statistics are intended to help you make sense of your data at a glance.
>
> ...
>
> - Filled/empty meters
> - Histograms
> - Frequency distributions
> - Email domain distributions
> - Key distributions

Comment: I guess you need to correct `INFORMATIONS_SCHEMA` with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

Comment: @ozgenbaris Yes, it should be the second. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent to `df.describe()`.

The simplest way might be a query that replicates it.  For example, you could compose a UDF that took as input the result of `get_ddl()` for the table and returned as output a query that had the correct SQL (min/max/avg etc) for each column.

If approximate answers are sufficient, one alternative would be to do what you described in a local DataFrame but implement a `TABLESAMPLE` clause to avoid loading all the data.

If you pursue the query route, the good news is that it should be mostly metadata-only operations which are very fast.